# add array to serialized form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, serialization

I'd like to updated selected rows in my table. Every row has an id (id is from the table in the database). So I try to add these ids to the serialized data. The array looks like this:

```
["1", "3"]
```

formData:

```
{"f_name":["tom","peter"],"l_name":["fel", "dan"]}
```

and I'd like to receive this:

```
{"id":["1","3"],"f_name":["tom","peter"],"l_name":["fel", "dan"]}
```

How can I achive this?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t6xkbdo0/

Comment: Umm, `formData.id = ["1", "3"]`?

Comment: @Ele Nothing happens. formData is still the same. :/

Comment: Please, post a verifiable example.

Comment: @Ele https://jsfiddle.net/t6xkbdo0/ I need the ids in the formData so I can update the database using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the elements to build the desired output, finally you have to send the js object as a body in the request.

```
let formData = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).reduce((a, i) => {
  if (!i.disabled) {
    (a[i.name] || (a[i.name] = [])).push(i.value);
  }
  return a;
}, {id: ['2', '3']});

console.log(formData);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll save this for further projects. I found an easier way to handle this :). But I upvoted your post anyway.